# pyinputplus を import しようとすると ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyinputplus'

Tags: python, python3

現在 Python3.8.2 を使っています。

`import pyinputplus as pyip` を実行しようと思ったが、以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

どのようにすればこの pyinputplus を使えるようにできますか。

初心的な質問かもしれませんが回答よろしくお願いいたします。

---

**エラーメッセージ**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyinputplus'
```

Comment: インストールしていないのでは？ [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyinputplus'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61503571/9014308) あるいはその類似でインストールした環境と`import`しようとして使っている環境が別々だとか。[PycharmのProject Interpreterでgymがinstallできない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/64015/26370)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。なぜか別の環境にインストールされており、謎めいたことが起きていました。解決策ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

https://pypi.org/project/PyInputPlus/

`pip install pyinputplus` でライブラリをインポートするか、環境パスが通っていない可能性があります。